# Add one last element to the end of FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to achieve the following, whereas all but the last are normal images coming from an array.

[image: Images]

Currently this is the code for the FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  data={images}
  numColumns={3}
  // ListFooterComponent={
  // <View style={[StyleSheet.actionUploadedPictureFrame , {height: PIC_HEIGHT, width: PIC_WIDTH}]}>
  //     <Image source={require('../../../images/add-icon.png')} />
  // </View>}
  renderItem={ ({item, index}) => index == images.length -1 ?
     <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       <Image style={[StyleSheet.actionUploadedPictureFrame , {height: PIC_HEIGHT, width: PIC_WIDTH}]} source={{uri: item.url}} /> 
       <View style={[StyleSheet.actionUploadedPictureFrame , {height: PIC_HEIGHT, width: PIC_WIDTH}]}>
         <Image source={require('../../../images/add-icon.png')} />
       </View>
     </View>
    : <Image style={[StyleSheet.actionUploadedPictureFrame , {height: PIC_HEIGHT, width: PIC_WIDTH}]} source={{uri: item.url}} /> }
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Which long story short, renders the pictures in the array in a table of 3 columns, and checks for the last picture in the list and in addition to rendering the picture, it also renders this plus sign.

However this is bound to have some sort of error if the list has a number of elements multiple of 3, since the plus sign would most likely be out of the screen.
If I use ListFooterComponent, it renders it in an entirely new line.

Does anyone know an effective work around to this?

Comment: What about adding it as a real element of your images array and handling its rendering in a condition inside renderItem prop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since I don't think I was clear enough, I'll try to explain properly my idea with this sample code:

```js
    <FlatList
      data={[...images, { plusImage: true }]}
      numColumns={3}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        if (item.plusImage) {
          return (
            <View
              style={[
                StyleSheet.actionUploadedPictureFrame,
                { height: PIC_HEIGHT, width: PIC_WIDTH }
              ]}
            >
              <Image source={require("../../../images/add-icon.png")} />
            </View>
          );
        }
        return (
          <Image
            style={[
              StyleSheet.actionUploadedPictureFrame,
              { height: PIC_HEIGHT, width: PIC_WIDTH }
            ]}
            source={{ uri: item.url }}
          />
        );
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />;
```

I don't know if it's the best practice to concat data array like that directly in the `data` prop, but you can always choose to declare it earlier in the render method.
Let me know if this can fit your request.

Comment: thank you soo much! I wanted to do exactly that but not understanding a whole lot about javascript (the 3 dots and concatenation) I didn't know how to do it! I'll check how it goes and possibly check this as the right answer :)

Comment: You're welcome! That's called spread operator, sooo helpful in react world (and js in general)

Comment: It is not an elegant solution. React Native should have provided the data list as a parameter of renderItem function

Answer (score 16):

I also came around the same situation and found a good way when I have check the documentation of `FlatList` so the best way that I recommend is to use `ListFooterComponent` you can pass a style object for that element using `ListFooterComponentStyle` [Click here for more details](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent).

[image]

Comment: As you can read in @Yokhen's question: _If I use ListFooterComponent, it renders it in an entirely new line_. That's why I wrote that solution.

Comment: Well, I think there is a style option as well which is `ListFooterComponentStyle` so you don't need to worry about style.

Comment: You kind of have to if you want to render components from different parents within a grid, which as far as i know is not possible.

Comment: This should be answer !!!